# Adding to Dictionary does not add

Tags: c#, object, dictionary, casting

I have Dictionary which contains string as key and System.Object as value.

```
Dictionary<string, System.Object> test = new Dictionary<string, System.Object>();
```

**I create and add values**

```
Debug.Log("Key:" + (string)KEY.obj);
Debug.Log("VALUE:" + (string)VALUE.obj);

test.Add((string)KEY.obj, VALUE.obj);

if (test.ContainsKey("id")){
    Debug.Log("contains!");
}
else{
    Debug.Log("does not contain!");
}
```

**Debug Console**

[image]

KEY and VALUE is an object of class

```
private sealed class ResolveValue {

    public readonly System.Object obj;
    public readonly int end;

    public ResolveValue(System.Object obj, int end){
        this.obj = obj;
        this.end = end;
    }
}
```

Where KEY is "id" and VALUE is "myData".

Took me quite a while to find the problem.
How is this possible?

**Additional information**

All string are converter from bytes.
Here's a debug i made.

```
Debug.Log("--------");

string msg = "";
foreach(byte b in bytes){
    msg += b + " ";
}
Debug.Log(msg);

Debug.Log("--------");

string message = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
Debug.Log(message);

ResolveValue response = new ResolveValue(message, end);
```

Variable *end* is an integer and has nothing to do with this problem.

[image]

Comment: Is there a space after 'id'?

Comment: Please provide a complete example.

Comment: Change your if statement to:  if (test.ContainsKey((string)KEY.obj))  so we can be sure.

Comment: @zmbq I tested that before inserting, but now after I've tested from getting it from object it acts weird. I even cached it but this is what it throws.

string t = (string)KEY.obj;
Debug.Log("Key {" + t+"}");

http://i.gyazo.com/ce6c9700e00d38756b3cebdad1d9644e.png

Comment: _"How is this possible"_ -- it's not possible. You are making a mistake somewhere in your code. But if you don't provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, it's not possible for any of us to point out to you the bug(s) in your code.

Comment: So obviously your string is not 'id' but rather something else. That's why you can't find it in the dictionary.

Comment: @ Tyler Day  Yes, your way showed that it contains, im lost.

Comment: Yeah, probably a space after id?

Comment: Nope, there is no space, if you look at the answers i gave to @zmbq you can see that doesn't even debug properly. Debug is printing anything i give. Debug.Log("Key {" + t+"}"); second bracket isn't even showing.

Comment: @Scavs, it's not showing because there *is* something after the 'd'.

Comment: Don't make us guess what your magic string is: [edit] your question so that your code is **complete** including where you set `KEY.obj`

Comment: Sorry, i added all information as "Additional information" edit.

Comment: This is exactly why im curious "How is this possible". You can see the byte amount is exactly 4, 2 for every char. And "id" is exactly "id" and nothing more. 
As soon as the question got "interesting", no answers or votes. I guess most of the smartypants and downvoters are very active when you can downgrade someone. Right now "Question does not show any research or effort", yep, i guess that it is what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two null bytes in your byte array that is getting converted to your string. They won't show up in the string representation, but they are different strings.

```
byte[] bytes= System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("id");
foreach (byte b in bytes)
   {Console.WriteLine(b);}
```

Yields

```
105
100
```

While

```
var b1 = new byte[]{105,100,0,0};
var b2 = new byte[]{105,100};
Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b1)==System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b2));
```

Yields

```
False
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am sending these bytes over a socket, so, as i understand, i have to keep 2 bytes per char for proper unwrapping, regardless of if the second byte is 0 - unneeded. Because other char might contain both. Could you comment of this?

Comment: If you're sending them to yourself, from yourself, then choose a padding scheme and unpad the bytes when you receive them.

Comment: I've made server in Java and I receive/send data from c# client. As i also had to deal with endians, I ended up not using Encoding class and made my own which converts straight to byte with correct endian without flipping with Array.reverse(). Unfortunately i can't vote up your answers, accepting the answer is all what i can do.